# I have a 3D plot with 4 points, I want one to be the focal point and the other three to have lines connecting them to the focal point

Tags: python, matplotlib

I used scatter3D to plot the points, but it doesn't seem like I can connect them. The cell is the focal point and the inj are the three it should connect to, any suggestions?

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

cell= [1258096.60,11285000.00, 9415.22]
inj_1 = [1267960.80 ,11278335.00,9430.9]       
inj_2 = [1267960.80 ,11278335.00,9441.32] 
inj_3 = [1267960.80 ,11278335.00,9453.99]

inj_cells = cell,inj_1,inj_2,inj_3

for i in inj_cells:
    I = np.array(i[0])
    J = np.array(i[1])
    K = np.array(i[2])
    
    plot = ax.scatter3D(I,J,K)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to draw lines use ax.plot:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

cell= [1258096.60,11285000.00, 9415.22]
inj_1 = [1267960.80 ,11278335.00,9430.9]       
inj_2 = [1267960.80 ,11278335.00,9441.32] 
inj_3 = [1267960.80 ,11278335.00,9453.99]

inj_cells = cell,inj_1,inj_2,inj_3

c, d, e = cell

for i in inj_cells:
    I = np.array(i[0])
    J = np.array(i[1])
    K = np.array(i[2])
    
    ax.plot((c,I), (d,J), (e,K))

plt.show()
```

[image]